# stepwise function graph, differentiability and geometric view (ray vs point)

Tags: geometry, derivatives

I am going through [MIT 1A: Differentiation](https://www.edx.org/course/calculus-1a-differentiation-mitx-18-01-1x-0) course at edX. It has this graph for some stepwise-function.

PROBLEM: MIT says it is a ray when you zoom-in at (0,1), I think it looks more like a point. I can't understand how it is a ray when I zoom into it. It is just a point.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a weird question, but the answer is pretty straight forward: it is a ray. If you "zoom in" at the point $(0, 1)$, you're never going to zoom in far enough that the horizontal line $y = 1$ is absent from the picture. There's no tiny gap between $(0, 1)$ and the rest of the line, so you can't "zoom it away".

Remember too, of course, that although the point $(0, 1)$ is represented by a filled-in circle, it is just a point, with no width or length. Zooming in will not make the point any larger or smaller.

Comment: From what I know about Ray is: "A line with a start point but no end point (it goes to infinity)"  -- https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/ray.html  . But this line does not have a start point, it goes from negative infinity to positive infinity, with a jump-discontinuity at zero.

Comment: @Arnuld Right, but if you look closely at the point $(0, 1)$, you won't see any of the other points to the left of the $y$-axis. But, you will see points to the right of the $y$-axis.